# Java Addition Table

Tags: java, addition

I have to make a two dimensional addition table for the numbers 0 to 12, but I have to use a helper method that takes an integer parameter and prints one row of the table. I figured out how to print the addition table without the helper method, but I'm not sure how to go about making the helper method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printCommonLogTable();
    System.out.println("");
    printAdditionTable();
}

public static void printAdditionTable() {
    int i = 0, q = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    for (q = 0; q <= 12; q++){   
    System.out.print (i + q + "   "); }
    System.out.println ("   "); }
}

}
```

Comment: Well, instead of doing two loops, one loop with `i` or `q` fixed (from parameter) should do what you want, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but I have to use a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

As your inner loop is the one that prints each term of a line, you can abstract out that loop into a separate function so that you have your outer loop calling your new function, and in that function you call your inner loop.  Pass any needed variables to the function as necessary.

Comment: I tried this but its just printing "0   1   2, etc." all the way to 12.
    
    public static void printAdditionTable() {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
            int helperMethod = 0;
        System.out.print (i + helperMethod + "   "); }
        System.out.println ("   "); }
    }
    
    public static void helperMethod(int p) {
        p = 0;
        for (p = 0; p <= 12; p++) {
        System.out.print(p + "   "); }
    }

Comment: Please don't post multi-line code snippets in comments, revise your question with your work in-progress below you've already written so we can see your work clearly.  

Also, from what code you posted, your helper method takes an `int p`, but then you use the same value in your for loop which you immediately set to zero, and increment.  That is why you see "0, 1, 2 etc".